# the limit of a scalar sequence in a sequence of scalars

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $(a_{n})_{n}$ be a bounded real-valued sequence. Suppose that $(b_{n})_{n}$ is a sequence (not necessarily a subsequence) in the set $A:=(a_{n})_{n}$. Assume that the limit $\lim\limits_{n}b_{n}$ exists. Moreover, assume that $(b_{n})_{n}$ is not eventually constant (we say that a sequence $(c_{n})_{n}$ is eventually constant if there exists a positive integer $N$ so that $c_{n}=c_{N+1}$ for all $n>N$). My question is the following:

Question. $\lim\limits_{n}b_{n}\leq \limsup\limits_{n}a_{n}$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: For the sake of precision: $(b_n)_n$ is a sequence in the set $A=\{a_m:m\in\mathbb N\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Denote $B=\{b_n\colon n=1,2,\ldots\}$. If $B$ is finite, then, since $\lim b_n$ exists, the sequence $(b_n)$ is eventually constant. If $B$ is infinite, there exists a subsequence $n_1<n_2<\ldots$ such that all $b_{n_j}$ are distinct. Denote $b_{n_j}=a_{m_j}$. All $m_j$ are distinct, thus $\lim_j a_{m_j}\leqslant \limsup a_n$.

Comment: Thanks, Fedor. You are right.